# How can you change the font of widget without changing the widgets geometry in Tkinter?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

When you make the font of a widget (in my case a button) bigger if affects the widgets geometry (height/width). Even though the character/word may not even fill up the whole space of the widget. Is there any way to get around this? For example: On this calculator (view picture) the numbers look bigger and easier to read then the operations, so I made the operation button's font a bit bigger (exaggerated in the image) so they too are easy to read, as result the 2 buttons are different sizes.

```
# How I made my button and how I displayed it.
myFont = ('Calbri', 14)
key1 = Button(root, text='1', font=myFont, command=lambda: keyClick(1))
key1.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)
```

[Please view this image of the calculator and code to better understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziHDM.png)

Comment: Please check this reference it may be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47127233/how-increase-font-size-in-text-widget

Comment: Thank you, I have check it out. Although I still have a problem, why does my text (for the buttons) take up like 1/10th of the space? Is there any way to 'expand' or 'fill' up the space. Also I know you can use 'fill=both' but that does not work on .grid.